# Why does @font-face fail in my style sheet?

Tags: html, css, font-face

I want to specify a custom font in my style sheet. I can get the font to work in a link statement in my html header, but I'd rather put it in my style sheet. When I uncomment the link statement, it works. Here's my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Font Bug</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontBug.css">
<!--  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Metamorphous' rel='stylesheet'>-->
</head>
<body>
  <p>This is normal text. It should display in a sans-serif font in black against white.</p>
  <p class="customFont">This text should use the custom serif font, in a custom color</p>
<p>When I uncomment the link line inside the head tag of the html file, the 
  font works. I don't understand why it doesn't work from the style sheet.
  I know it's using the style sheet because I get the custom colors.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my .css file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Metamorphous;
  // I have tried it both with and without the format specifier.
  src: url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Metamorphous) format("truetype");
}

.customFont {
  font-family: Metamorphous, Sans-Serif;
  background-color: #294575;
  color: #6291D8;
}

body {
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I misunderstood the meaning of the `url()` function. I thought it was for a URL to a resource on the web, but it's actually for a path to a local file. It turns out that font-face is actually meant for fonts installed on the server, rather than accessed through a URL. People have been telling me it's for "self designed fonts." This includes, but is not limited to, fonts you designed. I didn't design the font, but I downloaded it to my development environment, and set the font-face url to the relative path to that file (relative to the .css file) and it started working. I don't know why they call it the url function, but the alternative, local(), is apparently for fonts installed in the local computer. Thank you to the two people who answered. Their answers guided me to this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have implemented it the wrong way in your stylesheet. Try replacing

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Metamorphous;
  // I have tried it both with and without the format specifier.
  src: url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Metamorphous) format("truetype");
}
```

with

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Metamorphous&display=swap');

h1 {
  font-family: 'Metamorphous', cursive;
}
```

That seems to work

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Metamorphous&display=swap');

h1 {
  font-family: 'Metamorphous', cursive;
}
```

```html
<h1> Test </h1>
```

Comment: Well, that works. However, I have also read (https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/html-styles.php) that I should avoid using (a)import for performance reasons. That's one of the reasons I was trying to get (a)font-face to work.

Answer (score 1):

**@font-face is used to import your self designed font.**

*But Metamorphous is a web-safe font and it can be imported by using methods the other guy said already.*

Comment: Not sure who "the other guy" is here. And I'm not sure what you're sying.

Comment: As a general rule, you're not supposed to refer to other posters by name in your answer, but you're free to do so in your comment. This idea is probably more suited to a comment on another answer than to a separate answer. That way, you're free to address me or the Artemiss_0 by name instead of saying "the other guy."

Comment: I was talking about @Artemiss_0

Comment: I wanted to explain the cause of why font-face is not working. It is the basic difference between font-face and import. Self-designed fonts are not global fonts. You have to design that one. For these fonts, you can use font-face. But the font you used is a global font and it is available for everyone. So, you have to use import to add this font to your website.

Comment: Thank you. I think font-face is actually meant for fonts installed on the server, rather than accessed through a URL. This includes, but is not limited to, fonts you designed. I didn't design the font, but I downloaded it to my development environment, and set the font-face url to the relative path to that file (relative to the .css file) and it started working. I don't know why they call it the url function, but the alternative, local(), is apparently for fonts installed in the local computer. (I haven't verified this.) So now it works. Thanks for your help.